# Horizontal gallery - scroll and touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, gallery

I made horizontal gallery on wordpress using NG Gallery.

I'd like to scroll the gallery using mouse scroll-wheel and by clicking on gallery area and moving.
Now I can only move the images by clicking the scrollbar on bottom of gallery and moving manually.
How can i achieve it?

This is my custom code:

```
.ngg-galleryoverview {
  display: table-row;
  float: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-scrolling: touch;
  clear: both;
}

.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}

.ngg-gallery-thumbnail {
    width: 415px;
}
```

Comment: could you provide some fiddle or codepen with your gallery.....

Comment: @RenzoCC - I find the similar - it looks almost the same. In this case it is in clear html but the view is the same http://jsfiddle.net/mendota/w9dvp/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add this it is working on mouse wheel event whit this [library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel)
go handle the mouse wheel event

```
$('#footer').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    //console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
    if(event.deltaY==1){
      $(this).animate({scrollLeft: '+=10px'}, 100);
    }else if(event.deltaY==-1){
        $(this).animate({scrollLeft: '-=10px'}, 100);
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/0ogcnd9x/5/)

Comment: What I should insert instead "#footer" - in my case div looks like https://s10.postimg.org/st8fim915/div.png

Comment: could you help?

Comment: sorry for the delay......you can try to add .ngg-ajax-pagination-none instead of #footer, but I don't guarantee it, since I can't see the bug, try to reproduce the bug in a fiddle codepen or here ....   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve